# Examples of LaTeX used in business instead of Microsoft Word?

Tags: msword

Does anyone have examples of nontrivial uses of LaTeX in business? Obviously, technical publishing often supports LaTeX manuscripts, but what about other industries?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it will be a "big list" type answer, and those are generally discouraged even though some exist from the early days of the site. But even if we do end up with a big list it will mainly be people saying "I do X with LaTeX at my job" which won't really be of much help to others.

Comment: What is the clarification of "nontrivial" when referring to business? Math textbooks published by Springer that I've read are in LaTeX. | Some medical offices in my area use LaTeX to write bills. However in my area most of them are no longer even capable of writing bills themselves and instead have it done by external service providers.